# Set certain days of the week on repeat

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I'm making an attendance sheet for my team, how do I make only certain days like Mon Tue Wed appear in the top column?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(A1, 0)))), "ddd"), 
 "where Col1 = 'Mon' or Col1 = 'Tue' or Col1 = 'Wed'")))
```

[image: 0]